# Many QUdpSockets are dropped when they are sent in a short time

Tags: qt, sockets, network-programming, udp, congestion-control

I'm writing a program that will send a small UDP packet (about 100 bytes) to very many destinations (include some real destinations and all others are faked destinations).

If I send to small number of destinations, the real destinations can received the packets.

If I send to a huge number of destinations without a sleep between each send, just some real destinations can received or all of them cannot receive the packet.

If I send to a huge number of destinations with a right sleep between each send, just some real destinations can received or all of them cannot receive the packet.

This is the sample code:

```
void send()
{
  //about 10K addresses
  QList<QHostAddress> addrs; //include some real destinations and all others are fake destinations
  quint16 port;
  QString data("Data: about 100 bytes");
  QUdpSocket udp;
  for(QHostAddress add : addrs)
  {
    udp.writeDatagram(data.data(), add, port);
    //QThread::msleep(1); // 1 milisecond or 10, 100, ...
  }
}
```

Does anybody know that problem? Where does it come from? How can I solve it?
With my workaround (add a sleep), how can I calculate a right number of miliseconds?

Comment: As UDP is a connectionless transmission model, without handshaking, it is known for being unreliable. This may be the problem you're experiencing. Rather than sending to more than 10k of addresses, have you thought about using a broadcast UDP message? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Broadcast and multicast can work, but only in a LAN. It won't be routed over the internet.

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug, I am aware of that, though it wasn't stated by the OP as to which was being used, which is why I suggested it for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged as congestion-control, I guess you already have an idea of what is happening... Indeed, packets are probably dropped because of congestion. Since you send to many targets, the congestion certainly happens in your side of the network. The problem is that congestion isn't really deterministic, so you will have to make approximations.

One technique I know to regulate such traffic without dropping packets is to calculate latency to your target. If you have many targets, calculate latency to a known good server (even if it isn't a target). What will happen is that when congestion starts, the intermediary routers' buffers will start to fill, and it will significantly increase latency. Packet loss will start when the routers' buffers are full. What you have to do is to decrease sending rate as soon as you detect an increase in latency.

You may start with a low sending rate and increase when latency doesn't change, but be careful to not increase too fast, or packet loss will happen too fast to react (buffers are filled too fast and drop packets before you could decrease).

One problem is that the smaller the routers' buffers, the less time you have to react (and it can be too small to have time to react at all). Also, if the congestion is actually more on the side of some targets (if some targets are grouped behind a bottleneck), this technique won't help.

Another common technique, used in TCP, is just to retransmit and decrease the sending rate when you detect a packet loss. This means you need to implement ACK and retransmit. This technique is more bullet-proof but rely on packet loss, and therefore is less efficient.

You can also implement both techniques (ex: regulate with latency and retransmit if loss still happens) for improved results (more efficient but still bullet-proof).

Comment: I tried to estimate the rate: I send a special packet to myself, if I can receive this packet, I send some packets to some targets then resend the special packet ... receive special packet ... send more packets to more target ... . The problem here is I don't know my own IP until the real target send me this, so at start, I just send the special packet to localhost address (127.0.0.1). The special packet is sent/received very fast, so all others packets are sent very fast too but the packets are still loss when I check the real target.

Comment: The more question is: if the packet is sent to localhost, is it stored in the routers' buffers?

Comment: And another question: when I use two ore more QUdpSocket instances to send packets. Is it different from just use one to send all packets?

Comment: @ViDo If you send to yourself, there is very little chance it will be useful. Sent to localhost it won't even go out on the network, and sent to your IP, it will just stop to the first device that know this IP (often a close router, it can even be your own machine). This is too close to be useful to identify a bottleneck. Sending periodically a packet can help to regulate, but if you only monitor the loss, it is likely that it will imply a loss on the previous meaningful packets.

Comment: @ViDo About using two sockets, a practical difference will be that the source port will be different, and each one will only receive responses to packets they sent. Also, it will allocate a bit more resources, but it's probably not a problem (socket are quite light, and UDP sockets are even lighter).

Comment: Thanks ElderBug, I just use those sockets to send packets. I use other socket that binds to others port for listening. I just scare if there are a  significant different if we use one or more sockets. As you told, it's not a problem.

Comment: I just care that my packets are sent out my system/LAN/router (they are not dropped). If they are dropped on a farther networks/devices, it's not my responsibility. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @ViDo There won't be any difference network-wise if you use multiple sockets. It just change how you write your software. About the packet loss, I don't really know what you want, but keep in mind that even if packet loss on their side is their responsibility, making your software work is yours :)